# Embedded Keycloak springboot application, upgrading keycloak from 12 to 14

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

Hello I have an SpringBoot application with embedded Keyclock created using the below example
https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app

I am trying to upgrade Keycloak from 12 to 14 and also upgraded resteasy to 3.15.1.Final, infinispan to 11.0.9.Final. The application fails to start and there is not much in the logs except for a NullPointerException. I am trying to see if any one tried the same and has any suggestions as there are not much in logs. Thanks

```
2021-07-07 10:02:05 [main] INFO  org.keycloak.services - KC-SERVICES0050: Initializing master realm
2021-07-07 10:02:07 [main] DEBUG org.keycloak.keys.GeneratedRsaKeyProviderFactory - Generated keys for master
2021-07-07 10:02:07 [main] DEBUG org.keycloak.keys.GeneratedHmacKeyProviderFactory - Generated secret for master
2021-07-07 10:02:07 [main] DEBUG org.keycloak.keys.GeneratedAesKeyProviderFactory - Generated secret for master
2021-07-07 10:02:07 [main] DEBUG org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider - Going to release database lock namespace=KEYCLOAK_BOOT
2021-07-07 10:02:07 [main] DEBUG org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.CustomLockService - Going to release database lock
2021-07-07 10:02:07 [main] DEBUG org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.InfinispanUserCacheProviderFactory - Registered cluster listeners
2021-07-07 10:02:07 [main] DEBUG org.keycloak.executors.DefaultExecutorsProviderFactory - We are in managed environment. Executor 'java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default' was available.
2021-07-07 10:02:07 [main] DEBUG org.keycloak.executors.DefaultExecutorsProviderFactory - Found executor for 'storage-provider-threads' under JNDI name 'java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/storage-provider-threads'
2021-07-07 10:02:07 [main] FATAL org.keycloak.services - java.lang.NullPointerException

2021-07-07 10:02:07 [main] DEBUG org.keycloak.executors.DefaultExecutorsProviderFactory - Found executor for 'storage-provider-threads' under JNDI name 'java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/storage-provider-threads'
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$Stachtrace$$$$$$$$$$$$$ : java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
    at org.keycloak.executors.DefaultExecutorsProviderFactory.getExecutor(DefaultExecutorsProviderFactory.java:113)
    at org.keycloak.executors.DefaultExecutorsProviderFactory$1.getExecutor(DefaultExecutorsProviderFactory.java:68)
    at org.keycloak.utils.ServicesUtils.timeBoundOne(ServicesUtils.java:71)
    at org.keycloak.storage.AbstractStorageManager.mapEnabledStorageProvidersWithTimeout(AbstractStorageManager.java:135)
    at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.getUsersCount(UserStorageManager.java:374)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.getUsersCount(UserCacheSession.java:545)
    at org.keycloak.storage.user.UserQueryProvider.getUsersCount(UserQueryProvider.java:52)
    at org.keycloak.services.managers.ApplianceBootstrap.createMasterRealmUser(ApplianceBootstrap.java:99)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had similar vague error messages when upgrading our embedded keycloak to 15 in our Spring Boot/Servlet-style application. But we eventually fixed them by crawling through the code/history of the project that this [baeldung.com tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app) was based; thomasdarimont's [Embedded Keycloak Server running in a Spring Boot App](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/embedded-spring-boot-keycloak-server). This repo is a few upgrades past the initial tutorial; up to Keycloak 13. We compared the history to our code and applying/testing fixes incrementally for each version from keycloak 11 to 13. After that, the updates from 13 to 15 were a bit easier to understand, and the errors were not as cryptic.

Our application is not exactly like the example code given in the Baeldung tutorial, but below is a list of changes we needed to upgrade to Keycloak 15.0.1. These changes may not be 1:1 with your project, but hopefully these help someone save some time.

- In `KeycloakApplication` moved the realm-setup functions from constructor method to `bootstrap()` method. ([An example fix found here](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/embedded-spring-boot-keycloak-server/blob/master/embedded-keycloak-server-spring-boot-support/src/main/java/com/github/thomasdarimont/keycloak/embedded/EmbeddedKeycloakApplication.java))

  ```
  public class EmbeddedKeycloakApplication extends KeycloakApplication {
  ...
  ```

  ```
   //public EmbeddedKeycloakApplication() {
   //    createMasterRealmAdminUser();
   //    createBaeldungRealm();
   //}

   @Override
   protected ExportImportManager bootstrap() {
       final ExportImportManager exportImportManager = super.bootstrap();
       createMasterRealmAdminUser();
       createBaeldungRealm();
       return exportImportManager;
   }
  ```

- In the `EmbeddedKeycloakConfig` we added a couple new bean references/factories ([Both found here](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/embedded-spring-boot-keycloak-server/blob/master/embedded-keycloak-server-spring-boot-support/src/main/java/com/github/thomasdarimont/keycloak/embedded/EmbeddedKeycloakConfig.java))

  public class EmbeddedKeycloakConfig {
  ...

  ```
   @Bean("fixedThreadPool")
   public ExecutorService fixedThreadPool() {
       return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
   }

   @Bean
   @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "springBootPlatform")
   protected SimplePlatformProvider springBootPlatform() {
       return (SimplePlatformProvider) Platform.getPlatform();
   }
  ```

- In our keycloak-server.json, we removed the default 'concurrenthashmap' name from the mapStorage provider, but still provided the concurrenthashmap properties. This matches other Keycloak 15 examples. As Paul mentioned, the map_storage needs to be enabled, and the simplest solution is to use the system properties `-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.map_storage=enabled -Dkeycloak.mapStorage.provider=concurrenthashmap`. Similar examples can be found in the Keycloak test suites [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/testsuite/utils/src/main/resources/META-INF/keycloak-server.json) and [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/testsuite/integration-arquillian/tests/base/src/test/resources/META-INF/keycloak-server.json) . **HOWEVER**: We ran into errors when using these system properties, and decided it is not needed for our code. Luckilly, the 'mapStorage' is no specifically called out in the tutorial; it is only found in the [Referenced Tutorial Code](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/oauth-jwt/jwt-auth-server/src/main/resources/META-INF/keycloak-server.json). So we simply matched other Keycloak 13+ examples and removed the reference in the keycloak-server.json (shown below) to get rid of the null pointer exception.

  //Change this:

  ```
   "mapStorage": {
       "provider": "${keycloak.mapStorage.provider:concurrenthashmap}",
       "concurrenthashmap": {
           "dir": "${project.build.directory:target}"
       }
   },
  ```

  //To This

  ```
   "mapStorage": {
       "provider": "${keycloak.mapStorage.provider:}",
       "concurrenthashmap": {
           "dir": "${project.build.directory:target}"
       } 
   },
  ```

- Upgraded the proper infinispan and rest versions with keycloak version. ([Tutorial code reference](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/oauth-rest/oauth-authorization-server/pom.xml))

  < properties>

  ```
   < keycloak.version>15.0.1</keycloak.version>

   < !-- these should be updated together with Keycloak -->
   < !-- check keycloak-dependencies-server-all effective pom -->
   < infinispan.version>11.0.9.Final</infinispan.version>
   < resteasy.version>3.15.1.Final/resteasy.version>
  ```

  < /properties>

- We also added the temp directory location in the SimplePlatformProvider, since this field was required. **NOTE**: The system temp folder, used in the example, is not recommended for production.

  ```
   @Override
   public File getTmpDirectory() {
       return System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
   }
  ```

I hope someone finds this info useful, Good luck!

Comment: are you using embedded keycloack in production environment?

Comment: I've just updated my clone of the original code from Baeldung using your instructions and they _almost_ got me there. At least using Keycloak 16.x, I also had to change the mockJndiProvider in `EmbeddedKeycloakConfig` to return the ExecutorService when queried for any string starting with `java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/`.

Once I've made this change it all worked like a charm. Thanks a lot !

Comment: are u able to upgrade to latest version  20.0.0 or to previous version 19.0.0 ? if yes, could u pls suggest changes. Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: I am facing this issue https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-19-0-3-not-able-to-load-any-cryptoprovider/18046

Answer (score 0):

I’ve tried the same thing with keycloak 15 and I got the same result. It seems that keycloak’s ConcurrentHashMapStorageProvider isn’t taken in account.

**EDIT:** after looking into keycloak's code, I've found that MAP_STORAGE functionality is disabled by default (because the feature is tagged as EXPERIMENTAL). To resolve this issue you must launch your springboot app with the following Java option :

```
-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.map_storage=enabled
```

Unfortunately, I'm now facing another nullPointerException...

Answer (score 0):

I have applied the changes suggested by @mrieman to the initial baeldung.com tutorial. It works fine with 17.0.1 version of Keycloak as of now. Hope it will help someone. My repository on Github is [here](https://github.com/andreygrigoriev/spring_boot_embedded_keycloak)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31462430)